# Either coordinatorlayout or collapsingtoolbarlayout is adding an unwanted bottom margin

Tags: android, xml, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

As you can see in this screenshot the current layout is adding this unwanted margin/padding I don't want, and I'd like to remove it but I don't know how.
[image]

This is my XML:
I see that tweaking the minHeight off the collapsingToolbar or making so the toolbar inside gets pinned while collapsing is what makes the margin appear, I need that toolbar (the one with the circle and DaniloC on it) to be always on top with the tabs on being next to its bottom once the layout collapses, so either a fix or a way to circumvent the issue would be fine by me.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/user_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/Blue"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:scrimAnimationDuration="0">
            <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:id="@+id/topcoord"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/Blue"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/main.linearlayout.title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/profilebanner"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="146dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:src="#d5f2e8"
                        android:clickable="false" />
                    <Button
                        android:layout_below="@id/profilebanner"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:id="@+id/followButton2"
                        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                        android:text="Follow"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_margin="8dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_below="@id/profilebanner"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="9.5dp"
                        android:id="@+id/followers"
                        android:text="Followers"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="#2c302a" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/followers"
                        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/followers"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/followsNumber"
                        android:text="144"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textColor="#2c302a" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_below="@id/followers"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:id="@+id/Following"
                        android:text="Following"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="#2c302a" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Following"
                        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/Following"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/followingNumber"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:text="53"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textColor="#2c302a" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_below="@id/Following"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:id="@+id/profilename"
                        android:text="XX WIDE u NAME XX"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="#2c302a" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_below="@id/profilename"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                        android:id="@+id/biotext"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textColor="#2c302a"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. " />
                </RelativeLayout>
                <refractored.controls.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profileavatar"
                    app:layout_anchor="@id/profilebanner"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    app:layout_anchorGravity="center|bottom"
                    app:civ_border_width="3dp"
                    app:civ_border_color="@color/White"
                    android:src="#d5f2e8"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" /
            </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                app:title=""
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
                <refractored.controls.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_profile_image"
                    android:layout_width="36dp"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:src="#d5f2e8"
                    android:clickable="false" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="6dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                    android:id="@+id/usernamePage"
                    android:text="Username" />
                <Button
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:id="@+id/followButton"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                    android:text="Follow"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        layout="@layout/tabs" />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/user_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: you can't remove that  because it's your parent layout height

Comment: Care to explain better?

Comment: yes sure, your parent(window) view occupied full height of your device. And you applied 'wrap_content' for child views so reaming space always will display if you your child view not take full height of your device.you can see it if set translucent them for your activity

Comment: But the list on the bottom screen is long so it should take all the space, if I "unpin" the toolbar inside the collapsingtoolbar that space disappears as the list occupies the space as normal.
This invisible space also appears of the same size if I give the collapsingToolbar a minHeight of 48, and it doubles in size if I git it minHeight 96 and so on.
In other words the children take full height of the screen if I don't pin the toolbar.

Answer (score -1):

Alright after some random messing with the XML structure I managed to fix it, I really don't know what fixed it but here's the code if you're curious:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/user_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/Blue"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:scrimAnimationDuration="0">
            <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:id="@+id/topcoord"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/Blue"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/main.linearlayout.title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/profilebanner"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="146dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:src="#d5f2e8"
                        android:clickable="false" />
                    <Button
                        android:layout_below="@id/profilebanner"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:id="@+id/followButton2"
                        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                        android:text="Follow"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_margin="8dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_below="@id/profilebanner"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="9.5dp"
                        android:id="@+id/followers"
                        android:text="Followers"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="#2c302a" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/followers"
                        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/followers"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/followsNumber"
                        android:text="144"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textColor="#2c302a" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_below="@id/followers"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:id="@+id/Following"
                        android:text="Following"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="#2c302a" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Following"
                        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/Following"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/followingNumber"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:text="53"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textColor="#2c302a" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_below="@id/Following"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:id="@+id/profilename"
                        android:text="XX WIDE u NAME XX"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="#2c302a" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_below="@id/profilename"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                        android:id="@+id/biotext"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textColor="#2c302a"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. " />
                </RelativeLayout>
                <refractored.controls.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profileavatar"
                    app:layout_anchor="@id/profilebanner"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    app:layout_anchorGravity="center|bottom"
                    app:civ_border_width="3dp"
                    app:civ_border_color="@color/White"
                    android:src="#d5f2e8"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
            </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                app:title=""
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
                <refractored.controls.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_profile_image"
                    android:layout_width="36dp"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:src="#d5f2e8"
                    android:clickable="false" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="6dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                    android:id="@+id/usernamePage"
                    android:text="Username" />
                <Button
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:id="@+id/followButton"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                    android:text="Follow"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
      <include
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    layout="@layout/tabs" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/user_viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: please describe the solution which worked for you